# PHPmailer not sending messages to gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send messages from my website specialeducationnotes.co.in but not able to send the messages.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['query-submit'])) {
            require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            // $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               // Enable verbose debug output

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];

            $mail->From = $from;
            $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
            $mail->addAddress('specialeducationnotes1@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient

            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = '<h2 style="text-align: center;"s>Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'<br>Message: '.$_POST['query'].'</h2>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'Hello! Hola! Namaste!';

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                //echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo "<script>alert(' Your message could not be sent!');</script>";
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                //echo 'Message has been sent';
                echo "<script>alert(' Your message is sent!');</script>";
                echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php'</script>";
            }
        }
?>
```

I just get a blank page with no error message or any text and email is also not sent. Can you tell what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, what do you pass as `query-submit`?

Comment: Oddly enough, when you don't turn on debug output, you get no debug output to help you find out what's amiss. Uncomment that `SMTPDebug` line. It's most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, as the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide and many other questions on here discuss in great detail. It will also tell you the very first thing you're doing wrong is using a very old version of PHPMailer, though that won't help if your host is blocking SMTP.

Comment: Check out this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jp3qcasm/ @ArSeN

Comment: Debug output shows no error even after uncommenting that line. It just says HTTP ERROR 500 (unable to handle request). @Synchro

Comment: Then do what you do for *any* 500 error with PHP: check your web server's error log, where it will tell you exactly what caused the error.